# Serial Number in the form of week number in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have used this to get the serial number and count of distinct RepID's for each week. But instead of Serial number(1, 2, 3), I want the serial number value as Week 1, week 2, week 3. How is it possible? This is using SQL Server 2005.Thank you!

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) As SlNo, count(distinct(RepID))
from Reptable   
where Month(Date) = @Month
group by Datepart(week, Date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is `cast()` the `row_number` as a string and then concatenate `Week` at the start of it:

```
Select 
  'Week ' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) as varchar(10)) As SlNo, 
  count(distinct(RepID))
from Reptable   
where Month(Date) = @Month
group by Datepart(week, Date)
```